# couldn't load memtrack module error in android and show blank screen

Tags: android

I am working on android project and get error of couldn't load memtrack module, failed to load mentrack module:-2. I got some reference from other link but still got the same error. I got white screen when i run the program.

Below is my code:

> Android.Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gaubharat"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gaubharat.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" > 
        >           
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gaubharat.Product"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" > 
        >           
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.gaubharat.Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

<!--  Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> Home.java

```
package com.example.gaubharat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Home extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText contactnum, pass;
private Button hlogin, hskip;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://localhost/android/login.php";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private int count;
private SharedPreferences settings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    settings = this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);
    count = settings.getInt("count", 0);

  //  selectContentView();
    //setContentView(R.layout.login);


    // setup input fields
    contactnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactnumber);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    // setup buttons
    hlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    hskip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skip);         

}



//private void selectContentView() {

    //switch (count) {
   // case 1:
       // setContentView(R.layout.cti);
       // Intent i = new Intent(this, Cti.class);
        //startActivity(i);
        //finish();

     //   break;
   // case 2:            
    //  setContentView(R.layout.shopdetail);
     //   break;
 //   default:
    //    setContentView(R.layout.login);
  //  }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login:
        new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;

    case R.id.skip:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;

        String username = contactnum.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);


            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());


            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                // save user data
                 setCount(1);
                    // save user data
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Home.this);
                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("username", username);
                    edit.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(Home.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Home.this.finish();





                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }


    private void setCount(int count) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();
        e.putInt("count",count);
        e.commit();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Home.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }



}

}
```

> home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background11"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:maxHeight="10dp"
    android:maxWidth="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/contactnumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Contact Number"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="92dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/skip"
    android:layout_width="92dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Skip" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```